# A branch going from default to default branch in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, codeplex

I have pulled an incoming changes from a codeplex-based mercurial repository and have arrived at the following branches graph:

[image: mercurialdefaulttodefault]

Last changes were pushed to the repo by me from another machine.

Why do I have a graph branch from `default` to `default`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made revision 14 on one machine and also made revision 15 on another machine.  When you pulled from the central repo, you got the changes that were made on the other machine as an anonymous branch of `default`.  The solution, using tortoisehg, would be to right click on revision 14 and select **Merge with local**.

This is the same as it would have happened if another author made those changes and will happen every time you do work on one machine without pulling the changes made on the other machine.

If you want to avoid this in the future, then you should commit and push your changes when you know that you're going to switch computers and then pull and update on the other computer before you start work on it (although there's no problem not doing it other than the fact that you won't have changes that you might need when you switch computers)

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous branches have the same name as their parent. So in your case, it appears that your both changesets are issued from the default branch at rev 13.

Answer (score 1):

Because changeset 13 have two independent childs (from different hosts) and on pull you got "anonymous branching"